# BizTalk: Knowing send port finished write file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I has a problem with send port and an application: *The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.*

I guess the problem is while BizTalk send port is writing a file, the application pickup this file and process.

My scenario:

- I have an orchestration with a file send port to write a file to a location.
- After this port I have another send port to call an application to picking the written file and process.

I think: While file send port is writing and not yet finished, the orchestration does not wait but continue next step - calling application. And this leads to above error.

Is my assumption correct?

And how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct your orchestration basically throws the message in your send port and continues, but you can change this behavior and I'll give you a really simple solution here it is 
* Set your Logical send port like this 
[image: DeliveryNotification=transmitted]

Now your orchestration will wait for delivery ACK

*To make things cleaner 
Create a scope and catch the Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.DeliveryFailureException which occurs when you don't get an ACK

*Also add in your catch block a suspend Orchestration shape so you can resume your orchestration if your message doesn't get to its destination :)

This works with both File and FTP protocol, (I didn't test others)